# Authenticate User in Firebase through Katalon automation software?

Tags: javascript, java, reactjs, firebase, katalon-studio

I'm using the Katalon automation app, how do I authenticate a user? 
Should I be using cookies or do some sort of persisting to work around authenticating a user?
How can I authenticate a user with the Firebase database **in** Katalon?

Keep in mind; I'm using a testing automation app to test an app.

The app I'm testing uses React.js and Firebase with email verification to authenticate a user. The user goes to their email, clicks the link and they are redirected to the website where they can proceed.

I'm trying to authenticate the user without going to my email and clicking the link with Katalon. Katalon uses Java/Groovy and has a method for [executing javascript](https://docs.katalon.com/katalon-studio/docs/webui-execute-javascript.html).  It was suggested to use [this method](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/custom-auth);

```
firebase.auth().signInWithCustomToken("+token+")
  .catch(function(error) {
   var errorCode = error.code; 
   var errorMessage = error.message;
})
```

I can NOT get Katalon to recognize the `firebase.auth()`, I'm not sure how to import this library into Katalon to see if it works. I get the following error;

```
com.kms.katalon.core.exception.StepFailedException: 
 Unable to execute JavaScript. 
 Root cause: org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: 
 unknown error: firebase is not defined
```

The libraries I have imported are;

```
 import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth
 import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseToken.FirebaseTokenImpl
 import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseToken
 import com.google.firebase.auth.UserRecord
 import com.google.firebase.auth.UserRecord.CreateRequest
 import com.google.firebase.auth.UserRecord.UpdateRequest
```

None of these allow me to use `firebase.auth()`. However I have functionality as an Admin. 
Using the Katalon automation application how do I authenticate a user so I can continue testing the app?

Comment: It is indeed a client SDK call meant to run in a browser.  It mostly likely won't work in a server environment.  Client side integration is documented here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/start